# Perl - replacing numeric strings with content of a variable

Tags: perl, numbers, escaping, pattern-matching

I'm trying to replace some numbers in a line with the use of variables and i am running into problems i can not solve. Following Input:

```
    111111  133433.000  222222  5225.9860   360 01333.4400  90  10.37   137.71  190410
    111111  133434.000  222222  5225.9837   360 01333.4432  90  1.11    138.34  190410
```

The script should replace the value `1.11` in the second line with the `10.37`from the first line. There are several thousand lines in the to be processed file, so the lines will be evaluated and the numbers `1.11`and `10.37`will be stored within variables. In this particular case:

```
$speed = 1.11 
$speed_p = 10.37
$tmpline - current processed line (part of an array)
```

I am using this for the replacement:

```
$tmpline =~ s/$speed/$speed_p/eeg;
```

unfortunately this command ignores the "dot" in the `$speed`and i get the following result for the second line:

```
    10.3711 133434.000  222222  5225.9837   360 01333.4432  90  10.37   138.34  190410
```

So the command replaces `111`and `1.11`with the new value, is there a way to improve this and escape the "dot" in the variable?

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: Using double evaluation `/ee` is not only not necessary, it is dangerous and a very bad idea indeed. Because it executes arbitrary code on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The period `.` is a regex meta character which is a wildcard, it matches anything except newline `\n`. What you need to do is to disable the meta status of the period, which is commonly done with backslash. However, in your case, you can use the `\Q ... \E` escape sequence:

```
$tmpline =~ s/\Q$speed\E/$speed_p/g;
```

Note also that I removed the double evaluation `/ee` modifiers. They are not required, and they are dangerous to use.

It does not stop there, though, as you can still match `1.11` partially (for example it could match `21.1123` ). So you need to make sure you are matching the entire number:

```
$tmpline =~ s/(?<!\S)\Q$speed\E(?!\S)/$speed_p/g;
```

I use a double negation here, with a lookbehind and lookahead assertion, to make sure that the characters on either side of your number is not a non-whitespace. The double negation is meant to handle edge cases, as it considers beginning or end of string acceptable. If you are sure to always have whitespace around your number, you can simply use `(?<=\s)` and `(?=\s)` instead.

Comment: Great! Now it works how it should and thanks for the lookbehind / lookahead improvment!